# PHP echo makes HTML structure is incorrect

Tags: php

This is my php code

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
function mypic($arr){
    foreach ($arr as $pic){
        echo "<img src='img/$pic.png'/>";       
    }
}


$i = 1;
while($i < 10){
    echo "<p>".mypic($arr)."</p>";
    $i++;
}
```

the output I got is

```
<img src="img/1.png">
<img src="img/2.png">
<img src="img/3.png">
<img src="img/4.png">
<p></p>
<img src="img/1.png">
<img src="img/2.png">
<img src="img/3.png">
<img src="img/4.png">
<p></p>
```

However, I need to get the below output

```
<p>
<img src="img/1.png">
<img src="img/2.png">
<img src="img/3.png">
<img src="img/4.png">
</p>
```

How do I fix it? Thanks

Comment: You need to have `mypic()` *return* a string, not *echo* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
function mypic($arr){
    foreach ($arr as $pic){
        echo "<img src='img/$pic.png'/>";       
    }
}

$i = 1;
while ($i < 10) {
   echo "<p>";
   mypic($arr);
   echo "</p>";
   $i++;
}
```

Alternatively, you can have you `mypic()` function *return* a string rather than print it:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
function mypic($arr){
    $str = "";
    foreach ($arr as $pic){
        $str .= "<img src='img/$pic.png'/>";       
    }
    return $str;
}

$i = 1;
while ($i < 10) {
   echo "<p>";
   echo mypic($arr);
   echo "</p>";
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will tick it :-)

Comment: Definitely! waiting for the time to allow me to tick! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
function mypic($arr){
    $_str = '';
    foreach ($arr as $pic){
        $_str .= "<img src='img/$pic.png'/>";       
    }
    return $_str;
}

$i = 1;
while ($i < 10) {
   echo "<p>".mypic($arr)."</p>";
   $i++
}
```

Or:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
function mypic($arr){
    $_arr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $pic){
        $_arr[] = "<img src='img/$pic.png'/>";       
    }
    return implode(PHP_EOL, $_arr);
}

$i = 1;
while ($i < 10) {
   echo "<p>".mypic($arr)."</p>";
   $i++
}
```